# Is there Windows 7 Run as Administrator fix for Outlook?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-excel-2010, administrator, privileges

I have excel 2010 report which has a script that runs automatically emails report via outlook 2010 but it will only work if I have Outlook open via right click and Run as Administrator.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: not really. usually the correct response to UAC is to install a windows service that runs at boot as an elevated user, and have userland apps call it to perform admin actions, but in your case, you are running up against two boundraries; the one Outlook uses to prevent viruses from sending emails, and the fact that the admin action is coming from a userland app, and can't be easily shifted into a service.

Comment: You could always fix the script so this isn't required.  You can also set the shortcut for Outlook to always run as an Administrator through the shorcut compatability options.  Without more information we can't really help.

Comment: well I just figured out part of it. This excel file pulls data from Oracle so even this excel file I have to run as administrator, if not it won't connect to oracle and after data is pulled I have it to email me automatically but for it to send email me automatically  outlook must be open as run as administrator, however another excel file i have which as raw data doesn't require oracle connection it sends me email via outlook without having to run outlook as administrator. This doesn't make sense to me.